Help required in opening files of a dataset (.phys, .thermal, .pts, .ass extensions)
We have received a dataset that consists of audio, visual, thermal, and physiological modalities. Upon exploring the dataset, we encountered some challenges in opening the following file types:

.phys with the Physiological information
.thermal, .hist and .stat with the thermal information
.pts with the visual information
.ass with the auditory information

We have attempted various approaches to open these files, but unfortunately, none have proven successful thus far. We are not aware of the extensions used, and despite our persistent and thorough efforts, we have been unable to open these files. Please help us by guiding us on how to open files with these extensions.

If you provide more details about the dataset or share a sample file, I can provide more specific guidance on how to open and handle each file type. Additionally, if you encounter any errors or difficulties while attempting to open these files, please provide the specific issues you're facing, and I can assist you further.

With what tool/programming language do you want to open files?
